# excute method whenever object is created

Tags: java

I would like to know how to execute method, in java, whenever object is created.

for example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private Date dateCreated;

    public setName(String name){
    ...
    }
    ... some other methods ...

    public setDateCreated(){
         this.dateCreated = new Date();
}
```

I would really like for my setDateCreated() method to be executed on every object when it is created.

Comment: o really, I thought it was the same :S

Comment: Duffymo actually pointed out that you are using a setter here which also imho needs to conform to standards. Naming is everything in programming and I would name that method `setDateToToday()` make it private and call from the constructor like Talnicolas points out in his answer (that should be the accepted answer). Anyway, a `setter` would expect you to pass in the variable to actually set it to and if you ever want to use a library that expects that convention it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize, of course, that this class breaks the Java Bean standard as coded.

The standard will expect to see a Date object passed to the `setDateCreated()` method:

```
public void setDateCreated(Date newDate) { 
    this.dateCreated = ((newDate == null) ? new Date() : new Date(newDate.getTime()));
}
```

You're free to do it your way, once you add a void return type, but don't be shocked if other code that expects you to conform to the standard complains.

Comment: who said anything about JavaBeans?

Comment: I did.  Just pointing out that it breaks the standard that's been in place since Java 1.0.  You understand that Java Beans, POJOs, are different from EJBs, right?

Comment: it solved my problem. I added a call for the setter method in my constructors setCreated(new Date()); and it really works. thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Just call `setDateCreated` in your object constructor:

```
 public Person(){
     setDateCreated();
 }
```

You could also do it directly in the constructor if you don't want it to be modified later:

```
 public Person(){
     this.dateCreated = new Date();
 }
```

Comment: thanks, that is what I do but, some how hibernate can not get allong with this. My application fails with enormous stack trace saying...  Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer] ... AND SO ON

Comment: Is Hibernate depending on your object following Java Bean POJO conventions?  Ah, I thought so.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

use Constructors:

```
public Person(){
  setDateCreated();
}
```

also, `public class Person(){` should be `public class Person{`

Comment: true :) but it is not the reason hibernate fails to initialize

Answer (score -1):

I would use some sort of aspect oriented approach - that way you avoid having the code in your class. Check aspect j or spring for aspect oriented programming.

Comment: Not necessary.  And AOP approaches that don't alter byte code usually means proxying an interface.  How do you plan to do that with a ctor?  A constructor is far simpler.  AOP is a hammer opening a walnut in this case.

Comment: How would you go for logging on object creation? Spread that code over every class? If aop is no option - ok - if its already in (spring etc) why not use it?

Comment: I wouldn't log every object creation. Do you?  Really?  Besides, the moment you call "new" with a constructor, it's not under the Spring bean factory's control.